# Moto X Pure Edition: com.motorola.ccc has stopped

Tags: motorola

This has been happening for the past 2 or so weeks, and is not really consistent with me doing anything in particular.  I'll get a notification that com.motorola.ccc has stopped and then after closing the dialog, maybe 50% of the time I'll get "Motorola Display has stopped".  Sometimes I'll just get "Motorola Display has stopped"

Phone is unlocked and rooted but I've not done anything special beyond that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Me too on Moto G 2015 (3rd Generation), XT1543...

Comment: This is still happening to me but it's really weird how it does it.  I went a few weeks without rebooting and couldn't remember seeing the error. Rebooted and now it's happening almost every 10 to 20 minutes as long as the screen is on.

Comment: Mine phone has Android L and every 10 to 20 min a notification appears informing that there is an OS update (to Android M). Sometimes, another notification informs that `motorola.ccc` stopped. I think it is that update notifier that fails sometimes. I'm trying to use my phone with "Mototola Updates" notification unchecked, so I'll see if it fixes it... I recommend you to try it too...